# Add a counter in python every time name is written it goes up by 1

Tags: python

I would like the Buyer Number to change every time there is a new buyer

```
total = 200  # Assigns 200 tickets to variable total
sold = 0  # Assigns 0 tickets to variable sold
count = 0
while sold < total:  # Runs while loop as long as tickets sold is less than total tickets
    remaining = total - sold  # Assigns total - sold to variable remaining
    if sold == 0:  # If tickets are equal to 0
        print("Welcome to Movies4Us!")  # Prints "Welcome to Movies4Us!" if condition above is satisfied
    else:
        print('You are buyer NO.', count + 1, "." "The number of remaining tickets is now", remaining, ".")  # Prints user's number and remaining amount of tickets
    name = input('What is your name?: ')
    tickets = input("How many tickets would you like to purchase?: ")  # Asks user to enter desired amount of tickets to purchase
    try:
        tickets = int(tickets)  # Converts variable tickets to integer type
        if tickets > remaining:  # If user enters more tickets than remaining tickets available
            print("Sorry, there aren't that many tickets available.")  # Prints no more tickets available
        else:
            sold += tickets  # Updates value of variable sold into tickets
            print("You have purchased", tickets, "tickets, Enjoy the movie", name, '!')  # Prints the amount of tickets the user purchased
    except ValueError:  # If user inputs anything except for an integer
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a number.")  # Prints invalid input and asks user to input again
        continue  # Ends current loop and runs the while loop again

print ("There are no more tickets available.")  # If number of tickets reached 0, program ends
```

Tried adding `count = 0` and `count + 1`

Comment: `count+1`   =>  `count+=1`

Comment: `count + 1` is an expression that evaluates `count` and then adds 1 to the value.  `count = count + 1` would evaluate that expression (on the right) and then use the `=` operator to assign that computed value to the variable on the left, `count`, thus changing it from its old value to it's old value plus one.  This sort of updating of a variable is a common thing, and repetition is undesirable, so there is a special operator `+=` that adds to the value in a variable.  `count += 1` means "add 1 to the value in `count`" and has the exact same result as `count = count + 1` but is more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already initialized a counter: `count = 0`. You just need to increment it inside the loop whenever a valid ticket purchase is made.

Add `count += 1` inside the `else` block where a valid ticket purchase is made under the statement `sold += tickets`. This will increment the counter whenever a successful purchase happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the value of count, the easiest and clearest method is to update it on the line before the print statement. Alternatively, you could update in the other part of the code where you update the value of `sold`.

```
if sold == 0:  # If tickets are equal to 0
        print("Welcome to Movies4Us!")  # Prints "Welcome to Movies4Us!" if condition above is satisfied
    else:
        count += 1
        print(f"You are buyer NO.{count}.", end=" ") # Use string interpolation
        print(f"The number of remaining tickets is now {remaining}.")  # Prints user's number and remaining amount of tickets
```

I also updated this to use f-strings for formatting, otherwise you will have the problem of there being an extra space between the value of count and the following ".".

If you really want to not have a separate line for `count+=1`, it is possible to update count inline in the print statement, but only if you don't use f-strings, and if you do use the `:=` operator, because the arguments to the print statement must be expressions, so a normal assignment would be a syntax error:

```
print('You are buyer NO.', count := count +1, ". The number of remaining tickets is now", remaining, ".")  # Prints user's number and remaining amount of tickets
```